# How to judge "Impact" of Early Research

Tags: research-process, career-path

I am an undergraduate and  a soon-to-be graduate student. Basically, I am in very early stages of my research career.

I would like to know how to judge the "impact" of the research I'd be doing.
I am very "new", so I don't have much gut feeling
sort of a thing that senior researchers may have.

In particular, suppose I have multiple interesting potential projects to work on; or I see multiple possible extensions to state-of-the-art research. 
How to decide research on which one of these problems will have the "most" impact in some sense?
Does it even matter, or there are more important things I should consider?

By impact, I mean impact within the field , not [societal](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/166678/societal-impact-of-research) impact that this question mentions, although I work in an applied field so short-term societal impact also matters.

My question is different from [What are some formal methods in measuring socio-economic impact or broader impact of research topic or individual research papers?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/41907/what-are-some-formal-methods-in-measuring-socio-economic-impact-or-broader-impac) in the following ways:

1. I'm not asking for measuring impact after the research is done, but of "potential" research problems so as to decide between them
2. I'm not specifically asking for "formal" methods, infact anecdotal answers would be better

Comment: At this stage, it's better for you to learn your trade, do good, correct science and work on questions you find interesting, rather than focusing on "impactful" problems. If your science is good, it will have an impact.

Answer (score 1):

It is pretty hard (read "impossible") to judge the impact of something before you have done it. If you are doing true *research* (examining the unknown) there isn't even any guarantee of success.

But choosing a research path based on its "likely" future impact on the field seems like a wasted life. Rather, choose a path that interests you and that you have, or can develop, some skill with. If that path is generally accepted as having been fruitful and there are still unanswered questions in it then the overall result (for your career) is likely to be fine.

My advice is not to choose something that might end up boring you just because it is currently "hot". If the open questions in the field (subfield) are interesting to you in some way then that field is worth thinking about. Otherwise, choose something that will sustain you internally over some period of time. You can always change direction when you know more. Early on (especially undergraduate) you are mostly in the "skill building" phase. That will, hopefully, pay dividends later whether it has a lot of "essential impact" or not. Seek skill and insight in the short term.